# Mostrar imagens com efeito Cover Flow em Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagem

Estou procurando uma biblioteca que permita mostrar imagens com efeito Cover Flow. Mas tenho visto que as bibliotecas que o pessoal tem usado são de "terceiros".

Gostaria de saber se existe uma classe, framework ou API nativa do Objective-C, ou disponibilidade pela própria Apple para fazer isso.

Para que não sabe, [Cover Flow](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_Flow) é o modo de exibir imagens como se elas estivessem girando em um carrossel.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cover_Flow_on_OS_X_Mavericks_Finder.png

Comment: Tiago, adicionei o link pra Wikipedia, mas talvez você ainda não tenha lido... foi uma boa idéia?

Comment: Foi uma ótima!! não tinha visto esta imagem la! A imagem representante exatamente o que preciso!! Vou ver o link! Obrigado

Comment: Então quer dizer que a Apple removeu a biblioteca nativa para este efeito??? Então terei mesmo que usar alguma classe de terceiros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe um componente nativo. Você pode construir um usando UICollectionView com scroll horizontal, mas vai ser relativamente trabalhoso. Sugiro utilizar a biblioteca [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

É bem simples de usar e bastante personalizável.

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelLeão. Estou vendo que realmente vou ter que usar biblioteca de terceiro. É uma pena não ter algo fornecido pela própria Apple, pois é uma ferramenta visual muito bacana e que dá um visual muito bom nos app's!

Comment: Alguém a e já usou a API CFCoverFlowView para implementar o cover flow??